# monogid pluck returns duplicate results for embedded/nested fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

Monogoid pluck returns duplicate embedded results (not concerned about duplicate rows) for embedded fields.

eg: (user is embedded document for SomeModel)

```
SomeModel.where(condition).pluck(:region, "user.name", "user.lastname")

Results:
[["amr", 
  {"name" => "mark", "lastname" => "goodman"},
  {"name" => "mark", "lastname" => "goodman"}],
 ["amr", 
  {"name" => "john", "lastname" => "cena"},
  {"name" => "john", "lastname" => "cena"}]
]
```

I was expecting something like below:

```
[["amr",
  {"name" => "mark"},
  {"lastname" => "goodman"}],
 ["amr",
  {"name" => "john"},
  {"lastname" => "cena"}]
]
```

Similarly, if I query multiple fields from embedded doc, it creates that many duplicate hashes.

Not sure if I am doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why that's the case, but you can get the desired result using `map` instead of `pluck`:

```
SomeModel.where(condition).map { |m| [m.region, m.user.name, m.user.lastname] }
```

This should give you the results:

```
[
  ["amr", "mark", "goodman"],
  ["amr", "john", "cena"]
]
```

Or:

```
SomeModel.where(condition).map do |m|
  [m.region, { 'name' => m.user.name }, { 'lastname' => m.user.lastname }]
end
```

Should give you the results:

```
[
  ["amr", { "name" => "mark" }, { "lastname" => "goodman" }],
  ["amr", { "name" => "john" }, { "lastname" => "cena" }]
]
```